# Ошибка "Данный файл не найден"

Tags: delphi

Короче такая беда, у меня программа работает на ура.
У всех друзей она тупо вылетает.
Пишет такое:

> Данный файл не найден. Проверьте,что путь и имя файла указаны верно.

Все файлы на месте!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Даю 90%, что в проге указаны относительные пути, а у друзей неверно указана рабочая директория. Из личного опыта)

Смотрим [GetCurrentDir](http://www.delphisources.ru/pages/faq/faq_delphi_basics/GetCurrentDir.php.html) и переписываем все пути под нее.

Comment: Как его использовать, не понял....
Можно пример. Например, путь у меня записан так:

`'data/image.jpg'`

Как мне использовать `GetCurrentDir`?

Comment: Примерно так:

    var curdir, path: string;
    begin
    curdir := GetCurrentDir;
    path := curdir+'\data\image.jpg';
    {* и так далее *}

Answer (score 2):

У себя Вы запускаете игру с под делфи. Она правильно выставляет текущий каталог. У друзей - с иконки на рабочем столе или через меню пуск (у классной проги ведь должен быть крутой инсталлятор?).
Если Ваши файлы лежат рядом с исполняемым файлом, то  используем такую конструкцию `ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)`. Она возвратит путь к каталогу, где лежит Ваш исполняемый файл.
Используем так. Вместо кода вида

```
Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile('mycoolpic.jpg');
```

Пишем так

```
Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+'mycoolpic.jpg');
```

Понятно, что если таких строк много, то путь можно запомнить отдельно.
А вот использование GetCurrentDir ничего хорошего не даст (ну кроме проверки текущей директории).

Некоторые могут порекомендовать использовать `SetCurrentDir(ExtractFileDir(Application.ExeName))`. Да, это решит проблему, установив текущую директорию правильной, но нужно понимать, что некоторые функции могут ее снова менять (как к примеру диалог открытия/сохранения). Да, это все можно настроить, но зачем?

Comment: Тем не менее, глобальная переменная, установленная как GetCurrentDir в FormCreate, с обычной задачей вполне себе справляется. Запуск ярлыка обращается таки к экзешнику и CWD получается директорией экзешника, а потом уже смена не важна.